# Why is GDB outpting memory in decimals?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, exploit

I'm simply trying to examine memory in GDB. For instance say I fill a buffer with "A"'s, and then I find where my "A"'s start and then dump that memory value I the memory in decimals apparently.

Then whats weird is I didn't change a thing, tried again, and the "A"'s appeared (0x41414141...)

This is what GDB shows...

```
x/ 0xbffff558
0xbffff558: 1094795585
```

Why could this be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify how that data in memory is output. For example

`x/x 0xbffff558` Will output that memory in Hex
`x/i 0xbffff558` will output that memory as an instruction
`x/s 0xbffff558` will output that memory as a string

Additionally, you can specify the size of what to output

`x/10bx 0xbffff558` will output 10 Bytes in Hex
`x/10wx 0xbffff558` will output 10 Words (4 bytes per word) in Hex
`x/20i 0xbffff558` will output 20 instructions
`x/2s 0xbffff558` will output 2 strings